# Running java spark job sometimes gives message error initializing spark context followed by error cannot call methods on a stopped spark context

Tags: apache-spark

On running a spark program on spark cluster, I get message saying error initializing spark context followed by error saying cannot call methods on a stopped spark context. Sometimes on running the same job it runs successfully without error.

This does not happen always. Sometimes the job runs fine while at other times it gives this the above message. I tried restarting spark by using commands ./stop-all.sh and ./start-all.sh. I tried checking the logs it says started spark successfully. What can be the issue for this occasional error message. Can it be related to disk space or any other reason?

thank you...

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to have been occurring due to disk space being full in the nodes. I do not get this error now.Cleaning up the unneeded files seems to have resolved it issue.